# I have issue with data scraping with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code for data scraping from airbnb.com actually I want to scrape all comments with details like listing name, total revies, revies, commenter name, date, comments but my code does not execute the try part it directly goes to except part. please guide me on how can I fix this issue. thank you!
here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import pandas as pd
import csv

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') # 1. html , 2. parser
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):

    try:
        title = soup.find_all('span',class_="_18hrqvin",id=False).text
    except:
        title = 'empty'  
    print(title)
    try:
        reviews = soup.find_all('div',class_="_10za72m2",id=False).text
    except:
        reviews = 'empty revies'  
    print(reviews)
    try:
        total_reviews = soup.find_all('span',class_="_krjbj",id=False).text
    except:
        total_reviews = 'empty total revies'  
    print(total_reviews)
    try:
        total_reviews = soup.find_all('span',class_="_krjbj",id=False).text
    except:
        total_reviews = 'empty total revies'  
    print(total_reviews)
    try:
        commenter_name = soup.find_all('div',class_="_1p3joamp",id=False).text
    except:
        commenter_name = 'empty commenter_name'  
    print(commenter_name)
    try:
        comment_date = soup.find_all('span',class_="_1jlnvra2",id=False).text
    except:
        comment_date = 'empty comment_date'  
    print(comment_date)
    try:
        comment_date = soup.find_all('span',class_="_1jlnvra2",id=False).text
    except:
        comment_date = 'empty comment_date'  
    print(comment_date)
    try:
        comment = soup.find_all('div',class_="_czm8crp",id=False).text
    except:
        comment = 'empty comment'  
    print(comment)


def main():
    url = "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/34826867?source_impression_id=p3_1584615891_nVK823DKHNHuFWCQ"
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "does not execute the try part it directly goes to except part" - quite on the contrary, it attempts to execute the `try` block, but it raises an exception. so you go to the `except` block.

Comment: In `get_page()` you return a non defined variable `soup` if `response.ok` is False

Comment: and unconditional `except` is a very dangerous way of concealing all errors and confusing yourself when something goes wrong, because __you__ have made it invisible. At least put a print statement or some logging in the `except`

Comment: @ForceBru how can I fix it please?

Comment: @M.Akram, there's nothing to fix - your code works as expected: some of your calls to `soup.find_all` fail to find any elements and return `None`, but then you're trying to access `None.text`, which doesn't exist, so you get the exception that's immediately caught by the `except` block. I think that the `_class`es are generated randomly on each page reload as a measure to prevent scraping

Comment: Then any other ways to scrape this site?

Comment: just add return if not soup in get_detail_data

Comment: @Pavan Kumar T S  Could you please describe some more?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @arcticsanto there is your `get_page` returns `None` if a bad response is found so `get_detail_data` fails to get BeautifulSoup so just add validation for soup in `get_detail_data`

```
def get_page(url):
  response = requests.get(url)
  if not response.ok:
    print('server responded:', response.status_code)
  else:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') # 1. html , 2. parser
  return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):
  if not soup:
    return
  ----
```

Comment: If not soup:     return what we have to return?

Comment: Nothing, the attempt to get the HTML failed. `return` will just exit the function execution.